# Laravel 5 - Named route with parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my  *web.php* file,  I created two routes :

```
Route::get('/{name}', 'PublicController@index')->name('welcome');

Route::get('stats', function () { return route('welcome', 'enrique'); });
```

My controller looks like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PublicController extends Controller
{
  public function index($name)
  {
    return view('welcome');
  }

}
```

I already set up a virtual host in my local machine which is **http://blog.test**

When I Call http://blog.test/stats in my browser, it shows me the content of my homepage. But when I reorganize my twho route in web.php file in that way

```
Route::get('stats', function () { return route('welcome', 'enrique'); });

Route::get('/{name}', 'PublicController@index')->name('welcome');
```

***It works fine.***

Can you please explain why it behaves like that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the same route being overwritten. In order to have them both work, you will have to add something before your custom parameter:

```
/something/{name}
```

Otherwise `stats` is assumed to be value for your parameter `name`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel route goes to first matched routes, so in your case if it sees `/stats`

```
Route::get('/{name}', 'PublicController@index')->name('welcome');
```

It becomes variable `$name` for `PublicController@index`

[Check more article regarding this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/confused-routes)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because , when you add your {parameter} as after `/` , all routes defined after that, are considered as of that type

```
Route::get('/{name}', 'PublicController@index')->name('welcome');

// below routes not work 
Route::get('stats', function () {});
Route::get('test', function () { });
Route::get('hello', function () {});
```

same thing happen if you create new route like below :

```
 Route::get('post/{slug}', function () {});
  // this get routes are also not work 
  Route::get('post/show', function () {});
  Route::get('post/preview', function () {});
```

> so it is good practice that always define parameterised route at the
>   last

```
Route::get('post/show', function () {});
 Route::get('post/preview', function () {});
 Route::get('post/{slug}', function () {});
```